# How do you use ticks in bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I understand ticks, 20 ticks to a second etc. but i don't get the syntax. Can someone explain to me the steps of making something with ticks? I have a fireball move here as an example of something i need ticks for; after each time it does the effect, i need it to wait like, 2 ticks. I've looked at other examples but i really don't understand the syntax

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractBlockFireBall(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.MAGMA_CREAM){
        List<Block> targets = player.getLineOfSight((Set)null, 30);
        for (Block targetblock : targets){
            Location target = targetblock.getLocation();
            player.getWorld().playEffect(target, Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES,5);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know how to add a delay to a loop, timing is really important in this plugin i'm trying to make and i just need to know the syntax.
Anyone help?

Comment: It probably means that the effect will play every 5 ticks?

Comment: `5` is the effect's data.

Comment: Please don't re-use question posts. Leave existing questions to cover the original issue; you received answers for that original issue and you should not change the combined work to mean something different now.

Answer (score 3):

To make a timer, you can use

```
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    //code
  }
},ticksToWait);//run code in run() after ticksToWait ticks
```

So, if you wanted to wait 2 ticks before running the function `shootFireball()`, for example, you could use

```
Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    shootFireball();
  }
},2L);//run code in run() after 2 ticks
```

`plugin` will be the instance of your `Main` class (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`). So, for example, your `onEnable` and `onDisable` functions in your `Main` class could look like this:

```
public static Main that; //in your case "plugin" would be "Main.that"

@Override
public void onEnable(){
    that = this; //Main.that is now equal to this class
}

@Override
public void onDisable(){
    that = null; //Set to null to prevent memory leaks
}
```

So, your code could look something like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteractBlockFireBall(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if (player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.MAGMA_CREAM){
        List<Block> targets = player.getLineOfSight((Set)null, 30);
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.size(); i++){
            //call the spawnFlames with "i * 2" ticks, because
            //every time "i" is incremented, there is a new target block
            //which means we should wait 2 more ticks than the previous
            //iteration before running the task
            spawnFlames(player, targets.get(i), i * 2);
        }
    }
}

public void spawnFlames(final Player player, final Block target, final long ticks){
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(Main.that, new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Location target = targetblock.getLocation();
            player.getWorld().playEffect(target, Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES,5);
        }
    },ticks);
    //run code in run() after "ticks" ticks
    //"ticks" will be equal to "i * 2" from
    //the onPlayerInteractBlockFireBall() method
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, and the parameter 'plugin' is highlighted in red by eclipse. Should i have something assigned to it?

Comment: @Sporech I Just updated the answer with how to make `plugin` and instance of `Main` (you should read the answer so you can *understand* the code instead of just copying it, it'll be a lot better for you in the long run).

Answer (score 1):

You will start using [Scheduler Programming](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming).
Look carefully at [this part](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming#BukkitRunnable) of the tutorial.

You need a repeating task for this purpose:

1. First, create a class that extends [`BukkitRunnable`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html).
2. Then override the `Runnable.run()` method: it will be called once per iteration.
3. Now start the task with [`BukkitRunnable.runTaskTimer(Plugin, long, long)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#runTaskTimer(org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin,%20long,%20long)).
4. You can stop it at any time using [`BukkitRunnable.cancel()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html#cancel()).

You could implement the feature like this:

```
List<Block> blocks; // The target blocks
BukkitRunnable task = new MagmaEffect(blocks);
Plugin main; // The unique instance of the main class
task.runTaskTimer(main, 0L, 2L);
```

---

```
public class MagmaEffect extends BukkitRunnable {
    private List<Block> blocks;
    public MagmaEffect(List<Block> blocks) {
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }
    private int index;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Block block = blocks.get(index);
        block.getWorld().playEffect(block.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 5);
        index++;
        if (index == blocks.size()) {
            cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm getting used to the syntax, but when i applied this to my code, i'm getting an error. I'll edit my question to show the error.

Comment: @Sporech Just add an header like "EDIT #1" to highlight the new code.

Comment: Does this have to be inside a class that extends bukkitrunnable?

Comment: @Sporech Define "this".

Comment: If i wanted to put this all into an event handler class (implements listener), what would i do differently?

Comment: @Sporech You would put the first code block inside the handler.